# Retrieve specific rows from SQLite database on Android - For messaging part of application

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, logical-operators

I have spent some time researching possible answers on here for the problem as well as referring to the SQLite documentation and tutorials but I still cannot retrieve the specific rows from an SQLite database in an Android App I am writing.

I have a database of messages which I have retrieved from Twitter using the Twitter4j libraries and have stored then in the database, returning all the values and displaying them in a layout is working perfectly but when I try and get a specific chat thread it still returns all the values rather than just messages between the app's user and a specified contact.

I'm familiar with how logic operators work as I am part way through a Degree and have spent two years working with C++, however SQL is new to me.

It could be a case that I cant see the wood for the trees with this but below is the WHERE argument I am passing to the database query() method.

```java
//Values to replace '?' in whereClause
String[] userArgs new String[] { senderName, recipientName };

//Argument to be passed to WHERE in query method
String whereClause = "(user_screen=? AND recipient_screen=?) OR (recipient_screen=? AND user_screen=?)"
```

The outcome I am trying to achieve is that any messages between the sender and recipient are shown without other messages from the database. The column headings in the database are below:

- ID
- MessageContent
- Recipient
- Sender
- Time
- Profile Image

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want :-

```
String[] userArgs new String[] { senderName, recipientName, senderName, recipientName };
```

That is the WHERE clause has 4 parameters to be bound rather than the 2 parameters.

Comment: Thank you for that, it was a case of missing the obvious perhaps!